# installing UWP notifications nuget package

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to install

- Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications -Version 2.2.0

Nuget package for the following solution structure.

```
JSProj (universal App) - Targeting build 10586
    contains js App which has CSProj reference and can call C# method
    packages
        - Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.JavaScript
        - Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
CSProj (universal App) - Targeting build 10586
    contains C# methods that can be performed.
    packages
        - Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
```

---

For the JS project, `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` fails to install by throwing error,

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 2.0.6'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'UAP,Version=v10.0.10586', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

---

But it works fine in `CSProj`, but throws a runtime `IOException` for the package, when I try to call the notification in C# method.

I tried downgrading package versions, and changing the Target build. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can reference from JS project must be a Windows Runtime Component. As the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications#what-are-all-the-projects-for) for UWP Community Toolkit states:

> There's two notification projects...
>
> - Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications
> - Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.JavaScript
>
> The first project is where all the code is contained.
>   The JavaScript project is just for packaging the WinMD to work for WinJS projects.

This means if you want to use the notifications you must either use the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.JavaScript` package directly, or build a Windows Runtime Component using `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` and provide a WinRT safe class that you will use from JavaScript to access the functionality.

Comment: my runtime component is there in `CSProj` which actually throws the `IOExeption`. I initially tried the second method you specified. Do I need `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` in `JSProj` for this?